# Regex match between n and m numbers but as much as possible

Tags: regex, jsl

I have a set of strings that have some letters, occasional one number, and then somewhere 2 or 3 numbers. I need to match those 2 or 3 numbers.
I have this:

```
\w*(\d{2,3})\w*
```

but then for strings like

```
AAA1AAA12A
AAA2AA123A
```

it matches '12' and '23' respectively, i.e. it fails to pick the three digits in the second case.
How do I get those 3 digits?

Comment: Since not all regex engines are created equal, please provide a language tag.

Comment: Using `\w` also matches `\d` What are the expected matches for `AAA2AA123AAAA2AA123A` and should only 3 digits also match? What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The specification for the input string says that there is only one group of 2 or 3 digits. All other digits are single digits. I need the only group of 2 or 3 digits

Comment: @WJS Included. It's JSL - I'm not sure which flavor it uses though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the correct answer would be:

```
    \w*?(\d{2,3})\w*
```

Basically, making preceding expression lazy does the job

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you would do it in Java.

- the regex simply matches on a group of 2 or 3 digits.
- the `while loop` uses `find()` to continue finding matches and the printing the captured match.  The `1` and the `1223` are ignored.

```
String s=   "AAA1AAA12Aksk2ksksk21sksksk123ksk1223sk";
String regex = "\\D(\\d{2,3})\\D";
Matcher  m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

prints

```
12
21
123
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the non capture groups `(?:` as you are not using for example a quantifier or alternation. Specifying `\D` on the left and right means that there has to be a non digit on the left and on the right. It depends on if the OP wants to match multiple occurrences. If there has to be a word char excluding a digit on the left or right OR the start or end of the string `(?<=[^\W\d]|^)\d{2,3}(?=[^\W\d]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/k70ocQ/1 You could also write your pattern as `(?<!\d)\d{2,3}(?!\d)` if other characters on the left and right are also allowed, and lookarounds support

Comment: You're right!  Fixed.  Thanks.